# java array casting?

Tags: java, arrays, priority-queue

How can it be that i get a class cast exception when i try to do:

```
PrioritetArraySorteret<String> p = new PrioritetArraySorteret<String>();
```

the error is in the constructor?

```
public class PrioritetArraySorteret<E> implements PrioritetADT<E> {
private int capacity = 5;
private Entry S[];
private int size;

public PrioritetArraySorteret() {
    S = (Entry[]) new Object[capacity];
    size = 0;
} 

private class Entry implements Comparable<Entry> {
    private int key;
    private E value;

    public Entry(int key, E value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public E getValue() {
        return value;
    }

}
```

Comment: @BenCole - Arrays are no different than other objects when it comes to casting. It's just an invalid cast - you could no easier cast a `new Object()` to `Entry`

Comment: Huh, cool!  For some reason I had thought otherwise, so thanks for the correction! :)

Comment: @KublaiKhan - Actually, you _can_ cast `new Object()` to `Entry` just fine.  In fact, the given code (once the unincluded `Comparable` method is implemented) appears to compile just fine.

Comment: @X-Zero - I'm sure it does. I invite you to see what happens when you *run* the code though. A cast is a run-time check: you're promising the compiler that the object referenced by a variable has a more specific type. For example, the following code also compiles just fine: `String s = (String)new Object();`. Does that mean it will work?

Comment: @KublaiKhan - *smacking self* - Now I see what you were getting at.  I was thinking about external references, where the incoming `Object` reference _might_ be an `Entry` object.  As opposed to what's immediately going to happen, because it will _not_ be an `Entry` object.  Gaah...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error appears to be attempting to mix generics with something that can't handle this use of generics - namely, arrays.
Changing the definition of S to `List<Entry<E>>`, and the instantiation to `new ArrayList<Entry<E>>(capacity)` allows your program to run (given the limited sample).

Some other random notes, given your sample:

1. You've named your array-to-sort `S`.  Please follow the standard naming conventions (other people will expect you to), and give it a meaningful name.  It doesn't help that it may look similar to `5` (depends on font, I'll admit).
2. `capacity` is an instance variable used for initialization for every instance of the class (and nowhere else).  Change this to a `final static` variable and/or change the name of the variable to reference *why* this is the case
3. You define `size` - Likely, you should be returning `S.size()` regardless, unless you have some (unstated) specific need.
4. Your use of the terms `key` and `value` suggests you are attempting to use (or *maybe* implement) a `HashMap`.

Comment: I must use an array. But yes, i know how to do it with a hashmap. That would be easier.

Comment: @Uthen - _Why_ are you required to use an array?  Is there some specific reason the collections framework isn't available (I doubt this, given that you're using generics)?  I believe that `ArrayList` is backed by an array... does that fill your requirements?  There _are_ ways to wrapper things so you can 'use' generics with arrays, but I'm not completely sure that they're available here - you have to implement a class that _doesn't_ use generics, which extends/implements something that does - you would have to define the array _outside_ of the generic class.

Answer (score 4):

You really are declaring an array of type Object and trying to cast it, which doesn't work. Instead, in your constructor, do:

```
S = new Entry[capacity];
```

Comment: Interestingly, this doesn't actually solve the problem, although the compiler error it generates is interesting.

Comment: It does not work with  S = new Entry[capacity]; I get an compile error that says "cannot create an generic array"

Comment: Indeed. I was answering the question about class cast exception. Why don't you post the full class and/or the PrioritetADT interface so that we can understand why you're using generics, why you want/need to use an array member field, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you do a cast in

```
S = (Entry[]) new Object[capacity];
```

and not just

```
S = new Entry[capacity];
```

That would probably solve the problem.

Comment: Interestingly, this doesn't actually solve the problem, although the compiler error it generates is interesting.

Comment: It does not work with S = new Entry[capacity]; I get an compile error that says "cannot create an generic array"